# Возможно ли избавиться от undefined в интерфейсе?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Пишу функцию которая переделывает массив в определенный вид. Выглядит следующим образом:

```
const createComboboxData = <
  T extends any[] | readonly any[] | undefined,
  V extends keyof T[number],
  L extends Exclude<keyof T[number], V>
>(
  arr: T,
  valueField: V,
  labelField: L
) => {
  const arrData: ComboBoxData[] = []

  if (!arr || arr.length === 0) return []

  arr.forEach((item) => {
    const value = item?.[valueField]
    const label = item?.[labelField]

    if (value && label) arrData.push({ value, label })
  })

  return arrData
}
```

При попытке передать массив, который может быть `undefined` возникает проблема в том, что два оставшихся параметра не отображаются (что логично), но тип массива известен.

Выглядит это так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, сам вопрос. Можно ли как-то в `TS` избавиться от `undefined` и оставить чисто тип массива?

Comment: нет нельзя. В данном случае не доходит до вывода типов остальных параметров, так как все падает на первом

Comment: @Grundy. Хорошо. Поправил вопрос. Теперь первый параметр проходит, но остальные также не отрабатывают.

Comment: ошибка та же самая остается? Или меняется?

Comment: Первый параметр проходит нормально. Остальные TS поставил с типом `never`

Comment: Все правильно. ты пытаешь взять ключи у типа `a | undefined` - так как у `undefined` нет ключей - выводится общий тип `never`

Comment: `NonNullable<T>`

Comment: @sailybra. Дай вам бог здоровья

Comment: @sailybra. Оформите как ответ.

Comment: @SaNFeeD для сведенья, утилити тип `NonNullable` также убирает `null`-ы. Для того чтобы убирать только `undefined` можно написать собственный тип: `type NoUndefined<T> = Exclude<T, undefined>`